# Explain why the solution to the inequality is wrong

Tags: inequality

Problem:
$$x/2 - 4/x - 1 > 0$$

Simplified to:
$$(x^2-8)/2x > 1$$

Right solution (put all at one side, bring to one fraction) is union of:
$$x^2-8-2x>0, x > 0$$
and
$$x^2-8-2x<0, x < 0$$

Wrong solution (multiply both sides by $2x$):
$$x^2 - 8 > 2x$$

How formally explain why multiplying both sides by 2x is wrong here?

Comment: $2x$ may be positive or negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $x=-1$ in the inequality
$$
\frac{x^2-8}{2x}>1
$$
You can check that it is valid. Now multiply by $2x$ to "get"
$$
x^2-8>2x
$$
which is invalid for the  same value $x=-1$. The problem is that multiplication of inequality by negative number changes the sign of inequality. Formally
$$
(a>b)\wedge (c<0)\implies ac<bc
$$